# ckeditor - Double images pasted after copy with mouse right-click from browser in rich text field managed with ckEditor (in SFDC)

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to copy an image taken from browser,from another web page.
When i paste it into the field (Edit Form), i have the same photo pasted two times in the area,so the same photo duplicated in the field.

Doing a check, i have noticed from the browser (Chrome v. 79.0.3945.117 ) that after doing the paste action,in the field i have:

```
<p>
<img data-cke-saved-src="data:image/png;base64,XXXXX" src="data:image/png;base64,XXXXX">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,XXXXX"><br>
</p>
```

where xxxxx is the base64 string.

How can i remove duplicate image?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps i have found a solution (i will monitor the behaviour of the library).

Adding:

```
ev.editor.on('paste', function (ev) {
        console.log('some stuff');
    });
```

i 've realized that the paste event arises for two times ( it is an unespected behaviour of ckEditor?) when i make the paste action with mouse or ctrl-v.

Anyway adding:

```
ev.data.html = ev.data.html.replace(/<imgimg data-cke-saved-src( [^>]*)?>/gi, '');
```

i have removed the first image apparently generated by CKeditor.